# Linker can not open libboost_signals-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib

Tags: qt, boost, shared-libraries

I m trying to build a project which uses boost libraries. When trying to compile it I get some linker errors which I m not able to solve. I get

```
:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_signals-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib'
```

To resolve this error I have put these lines in my .pro file

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_signals-vc100-mt-gd-1_48

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../boost_1_48_0/stage
```

I'm using dynamic libraries, but qmake automatically searches for static libraries. Adding above lines didn't solve the problem. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you link with CRT statically (/MT or /MTd), the static boost libs are selected automatically. If you want to force linking dynamic boost libs, define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK, but linking static CRT and dynamic boost is not a good idea.